# mod rewrite for url, Internal Server Error, Kind of works when I put ? after the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I uploaded a project to a directory. I have a subdomain which points to this directory.

```
root/foo   =>   foo.mydomain.com
```

When I go to foo.mydomain.com, I get the error "Internal Server Error", I'm sure this has to do with .htaccess, but I haven't got a clue where to go. Do I put the .htaccess in the root? or the folder which points to my subdomain.

So to Summarize:
I have a subdomain foo.mydomain.com, this points to a directory in my root (root/foo/index.php).
I need a .htaccess file which can resolve this error. My Current .htaccess file is here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I know this .htaccess file is wrong, because it was what I used on my localhost, Where this project was in the root. Now I've taken it out the root, I need a working .htaccess to fix this. What do I need to edit in the above code to make my project work.
Project: root/foo/index.php <-- This is where my project is(directory called "foo")
I also have a subdomain pointing to ^^ The said directory.

Comment: Are you sure these 4 lines are causing the Internal Server Error (and which line)? Also check if index.php isn't throwing the Internal Server Error

Comment: Have you looked in the error log to see the cause of the 500 error?

Comment: As long as that `.htaccess` file is in `root/foo`, it looks correct enough

Comment: I gave up on this, couldnt find the answer.

Comment: I am also with the same issue :( . But mine is a shared server, so I don't have any access to error log. What I understand is the `AllowOverride All` issue. But have been asking the server people. When you move to /dev folder and point changing the `RewriteBase /dev` . This works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I too was having the same issue. Just now I fixed after trying a lot :D . Add `RewriteBase` :) .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope it will work for you too.